# Ruby Script: undefined method `symbolize_keys' error loading YAML files

Tags: ruby, scripting, yaml

I have a ruby script for yaml merging as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'yaml'

raise "wrong number of parameters" unless ARGV.length == 2

y1 = YAML.load_file(ARGV[0]).symbolize_keys
y2 = YAML.load_file(ARGV[1]).symbolize_keys
puts y1.merge!(y2).to_yaml
```

when I execute it:

```
./test.rb ./src/api/config/config1.yml ./src/api/config/config2.yml
```

I've got the following error:

```
./test.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `symbolize_keys' for {"root"=>{"cloud.n2"=>{"accessKey"=>"I5VAJUYNR4AAKIZDH777"}}}:Hash (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Do you have Rails installed?

Comment: `symbolize_keys` comes from activesupport in Rails. You will need to `require` activesupport as well.

Answer (score 5):

[Hash#`symbolize_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys) method comes from `activesupport` gem (activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb).

In order to use it, you need to add the following line to your script:

```
require "active_support"
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers/comments are correct it seems like overkill to require all of `ActiveSupport` for this. Instead either use:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/keys'
```

Or if you have control over the yml files then just make the keys symbols there and avoid any transformation. For Example

```
require 'yaml'
yml = <<YML
:root:
  :cloud.n2:
    :accessKey: "I5VAJUYNR4AAKIZDH777"
YML
YAML.load(yml)
#=> {:root=>{:"cloud.n2"=>{:accessKey=>"I5VAJUYNR4AAKIZDH777"}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not really the answer your question, but Ruby 2.5.0 introduced [`Hash#transform_keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) ([release notes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/12/25/ruby-2-5-0-released/)) which also can be used to symbolize keys and is in core Ruby.

```
{'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}.transform_keys(&:to_sym)
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

There is also a bang version which mutates the hash instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

As other have already noted, `symbolize_keys` is an `ActiveSupport` method. If you are not using `ActiveSupport`, and/or on a pre-2.5 version of Ruby that does not include `transform_keys`, you could define it yourself.

```
class Hash

  def transform_keys
    return enum_for(:transform_keys) unless block_given?
    result = self.class.new
    each_key do |key|
      result[yield(key)] = self[key]
    end
    result
  end

  def transform_keys!
    return enum_for(:transform_keys!) unless block_given?
    keys.each do |key|
      self[yield(key)] = delete(key)
    end
    self
  end

  def symbolize_keys
    transform_keys{ |key| key.to_sym rescue key }
  end

  def symbolize_keys!
    transform_keys!{ |key| key.to_sym rescue key }
  end
end
```

This is not to say that there are not likely other dependencies on Rails or ActiveSupport that will be required for your script.